# FXML HBox.hgrow property on tag fails with enum error

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to convert some working JavaFX code to FXML. I had tried the following, but I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javafx.scene.layout.Priority.Always

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Priority ?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <HBox>
        <Button text="License" />
        <Button text="Credits" />
        <Pane HBox.hgrow="Always"></Pane>
        <Button text="Exit" />
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

I then tried it a different way, which works, however I don't understand why the first one does not, while the second one does. I've seen code examples of the first way on here, has something changed and the code samples are too old, am I missing some import, or have I completely failed to understand what I'm doing?

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Priority ?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <HBox>
        <Button text="License" />
        <Button text="Credits" />
        <Pane>
            <HBox.hgrow><Priority fx:value="ALWAYS" /></HBox.hgrow>
        </Pane>
        <Button text="Exit" />
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you change it to `<Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"></Pane>`?

Comment: @James_D That could very well be it. Gotta love typos.

Comment: Use [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Answer (score 1):

James_D above got it, turns out I had a typo. Sometimes extra eyes catch stupidity.

> Changed

```
<Pane>
    <HBox.hgrow><Priority fx:value="ALWAYS" /></HBox.hgrow>
</Pane>
```

> To

```
<Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"></Pane>
```